# How to define project version in Azure Boards?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, jira, release-management, azure-boards

All

I'd like to create some project release versions(released and unreleased). In JIRA, you can find these versions in following JSON file. I need these versions to associate with work items in Azure boards. For example, to show a work item (Type: Bug) is found in certain version. My project is not built on Azure pipeline, So I don't have any release pipeline, so Is there any way to define these versions and name them with whatever name I want. Thanks.

```
https://jira.XXXX.com/rest/api/latest/project/XXXXX/versions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we seem have no method to directly link work items on Azure Boards to the 3rd-party CI/CD pipelines. Only Azure Pipelines is supported.

As a workaround, you can try to add a custom field on the work item to show the related release as the field value.

For example, add a text field named "**Release**" on the Bug item, then you can fill this field with the release version or the URL of the related release.

[image]

[image]

In the 3rd-party CI/CD pipelines, you can set up a step to execute the REST API "[Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to automatically fill the release version in the field.

Comment: Thanks, @Bright Ran-MSFT.  lets say that custom field version is a picklist and its version list is getting longer. Is there any API for .net program that can get this frequently-updated version list. As mentioned in the question, In Jira, you can get the version list in a JSON file